# Crashed When testing my app (using swift) on a physical device, Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x120021088)

Tags: ios, swift, testing, crash, breakpoints

I have a problem when running my app on a physical device, but it works fine when I run that on a simulator.

Error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x120021088)

Logs:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E769751-670F-4E12-90D3-A51C3DC14793/CenterBrain.app/CenterBrain
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E769751-670F-4E12-90D3-A51C3DC14793/CenterBrain.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x1001F8000, size=0x0015C000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E769751-670F-4E12-90D3-A51C3DC14793/CenterBrain.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib

And here is the screenshot:
[image: screen shot]

P.S. I did't put my code up here because I just ran it on my iPhone and it worked fine, after that I didn't change a single line of my code.

P.P.S Anyone got this error before?

Comment: did you update your xcode or iphone OS?

Comment: This msg caught my eye: `Reason: no suitable image found`. Might want to check your assets.

Comment: But I didn't change anything in this project and it works fine on simulator @KelvinLau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updatng the xcode to the latest beta version.